# overriding default Parallel Collections behavior in scala

Tags: multithreading, performance, scala, parallel-processing

I have a large batched parallel computation that I use a parallel map for in scala.  I have noticed that there appears to be a gradual downstepping of CPU usage as the workers finish.  It all comes down to a call to a call inside of the Map object

```
scala.collection.parallel.thresholdFromSize(length, tasksupport.parallelismLevel)
```

Looking at the code, I see this:

```
def thresholdFromSize(sz: Int, parallelismLevel: Int) = {
  val p = parallelismLevel
  if (p > 1) 1 + sz / (8 * p)
  else sz
}
```

My calculation works great on a large number of cores, and now I understand why..

```
thesholdFromSize(1000000,24) = 5209
thesholdFromSize(1000000,4) = 31251
```

If I have an array of length 1000000 on 24 CPU's it will partition all the way down to 5209 elements.  If I pass that same array into the parallel collections on my 4 CPU machine, it will stop partitioning at 31251 elements.

It should be noted that the runtime of my calculations is not uniform.  Runtime per unit can be as much as 0.1 seconds.  At 31251 items, that's 3100 seconds, or 52 minutes of time where the other workers could be stepping in and grabbing work, but are not.  I have observed exactly this behavior while monitoring CPU utilization during the parallel computation.  Obviously I'd love to run on a large machine, but that's not always possible.

My question is this:  Is there any way to influence the parallel collections to give it a smaller threshold number that is more suited to my problem?  The only thing I can think of is to make my own implementation of the class 'Map', but that seems like a very non-elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

You want to read up on [Configuring Scala parallel collections](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/parallel-collections/configuration.html). In particular, you probably need to implement a TaskSupport trait.

Comment: lets assume that I already read up on that (which is what caused me to start digging in the code).  I have found very little on how one would go about actually implementing a TaskSupport trait

Comment: @fbl ah. Then I probably can't help that much more :-\

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is something like this:

```
yourCollection.tasksupport = new ForkJoinTaskSupport(new scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool(24))
```

The `parallelism` parameter defaults to the number of CPU cores that you have, but you can override it like above. This is shown in the source for `ParIterableLike` as well.

Comment: but wouldn't that just spawn 24 workers?  I only have 4 cores on this machine, so I only want 4 workers.  The problem is that for very large input sizes, some workers finish significantly faster than others, which seems to be governed by the thresholdFromSize() function mentioned in the original question.

Answer (score 0):

0.1 second is large time enough to handle it separately. Wrap processing of each unit (or 10 units) in a separate Runnable and submit all of them to a FixedThreadPool. Another approach is to use ForkJoinPool - then it is easier to control the end of all computations.